# Boundedness of a linear functional in $L^2$, composition of a continuous and integrable function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

How to prove that the linear functional is bounded or continuous?
$$y \mapsto \int_\Omega g(u(x))\: y(x)dx \enspace\enspace\enspace (1)$$

We have $u,y \in W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega).$ $\Omega$ is open and bounded,  $g$ is continuous, decreasing and $ |g(s)|\le c|s|^{q-1}\;\;\text{for} \; \forall s \in \Bbb R.$
$q$ depends on dimension $d$ for $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^{d}.$
For $d=1$ there is no problem because $W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is embedded in $C([0,1]).$

I have to get something like: $|\int_\Omega g(u(x))\: y(x)dx|\le C \;\lVert y\rVert_{H}.$

I take $H = (W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega), || \nabla \cdot ||).$ Because of Poincaré inequality, this norm is equivalent to the classic $W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega)$ norm. Moreover, $H$ is a separable, reflexive Hilbert space.

If I show that $(1)$ is bounded then by the Riesz representation theorem there exists a vector $G(u) \in H$ such that $\langle G(u) |y\rangle_{H} = \int_\Omega g(u(x))\: y(x)dx$.
Then in the next step I want to prove that such $G:H \mapsto H$ is a nonlinear continuous operator, but that is for an other question.

My question comes from trying to prove the existence of a weak solution for the Dirichlet boundary problem:
$$-\Delta u(x)= g(u(x)) + h(x) \; \; \; x\in \Omega, \;\\ u\equiv0 \;  \;\;x \in \partial\Omega$$

In classroom, we've proven this Theorem:
$$Let \;H\; be\; a\; real \;Hilbert\; space\; and\\
 T:H\to H\; a\; continuous,\; monotonic\; and\; weakly \;coercive \; operator.\\
Then \;T(H)=H.\\ If \; T \; is \;strongly \;monotonic, \;then \;T \;is \;injection.$$

In the weak formulation:
\begin{equation}\int_\Omega \nabla u(x)\nabla y(x) dx \enspace - \int_{\partial{\Omega}} y(x) \nabla_{\vec{n}}u(x)d\sigma(x) = \int_\Omega g(u(x))\: y(x)dx + \int_\Omega h(x)y(x)dx\end{equation}

Here I define $T:H \mapsto H, T = J-G$,where
$$ \langle J(u) |y\rangle_{H} = \int_\Omega \nabla u(x) \nabla y(x)dx$$
$$ \langle G(u) |y\rangle_{H} = \int_\Omega g(u(x))\: y(x)dx$$
$$\langle h^* |y\rangle_{H} = \int_\Omega h(x)\: y(x)dx, \enspace \enspace h^* \text{and} \; h \text{ are not the same}.$$

I've proven that T is strongly monotonic because function $g$ is decreasing and therefore weakly coercitive. J is identity operator, so it is continuous.
I'm trying to show that G is continuous.

Comment: I suppose that by $W_0^{1,2}$ you mean Sobolev space $\{y \in L^2:\nabla y\in L^2(\Omega;\mathbb R^d) \}$

Comment: Yes, that space. An other way to define it is:  $ \{ y \in L^2 : \exists \text{every partial  derivative in weak sense} \}$